# How much does adding functions affect the execution time?

Tags: javascript

Two codes are written to achieve the same objective. The one with more functions executed slowly compared to the other. I want to why this happens and whether it is a good practice or not.

**Run this code on this website and check.** - [https://stanford.edu/~cpiech/karel/ide.html](https://stanford.edu/%7Ecpiech/karel/ide.html)

**Code 1(less functions):**

```
function main(){
   beepers3Right();
   move();
   beepers2Left();
   beepers3Right();
   move();
   beepers2Left();
   beepers3Right();
}

function beepers3Right() {
   putBeeper();
   move();
   move();
   putBeeper();
   move();
   move();
   putBeeper();
   turnLeft();
}

function beepers2Left() {
   turnLeft();
   move();
   putBeeper();
   move();
   move();
   putBeeper();
   move();
   turnRight();
   move();
   turnRight();
}
```

**Code 2(more funstions)**

```
function main(){
   outer();
   moveDiagonal();
   inner();
   moveDiagonal();
}

function move2x(){
   move();
   move();
}

function moveStraightBeeper(){
   putBeeper();
   move2x();
}

function innerMove(){
   move2x();
   putBeeper();
   turnLeft();
}

function moveDiagonal(){
   move();
   turnLeft();
   move();
   turnRight();
   putBeeper();
}

function outerMove(){
   moveStraightBeeper();
   moveStraightBeeper();
   turnLeft();
}

function outer(){
   outerMove();
   outerMove();
   outerMove();
   outerMove();
}

function inner(){
   innerMove();
   innerMove();
   innerMove();
}
```

Comment: I cant speak on behalf of this website specifically, but generally speaking there isn't a performance cost to calling functions. https://www.codereadability.com/performance-cost-javascript-function-call-and-foreach/

Comment: What makes you think one code runs faster than the other?

Comment: It depends on the use case but generally speaking - if your extra functions make it easier to understand your code or reduce repetition then this is usually preferable over minor speed increases.

Comment: @jack Let's say if our building a huge game. what would happen then? I just want to know how much it will affect apart from readability what are the other benefits?

Comment: @Etheryte I tested both codes with a stop timer and found that one of them was completing the task faster.

Comment: The cost of function calls themselves is pretty negligible, what creates the impact is the functions contents. Multiple calls to a complicated function will decrease performance more than multiple calls to a simple function. Focus on optimising each functions contents rather than worrying about the number of functions/calls you use for the same logic.